# Java - Zipping files from websites?

Tags: java, web, zip, directory

I just wanted to know how can I zip a file on the web using java, of course.

I know how to do this for directories on the hard drive, but not for websites:

```
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("C:/Documents and Settings/User/desktop/something.file");
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean "a file on the web" ? As in something you're receiving from a remove site via a `HttpUrlConnection`?

Comment: Well basically, instead of zipping a file located on your hard drive - I wanted it to zip a file from a webserver, given the address of http://blahblablah.com/file.txt (this is what I meant by "from the web").

Comment: If you mean you want the file compressed on the web server and sent to your program already compressed, then you can't. The server would need to do that for you and send you the compressed file.  Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: So your input is coming from a URL, but where do you want your output to go? URL, File, byte array? What do you want to do with the zipped "file", why not download it into a file first and then ZIP it locally?

Answer (score 1):

So I take it that you want to download and compress a file. That's two different tasks, so you need two things to do it:

- something to download the file from the web
- something to compress it into a zip file

I suggest that you use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) to download the file, and [Apache Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) to compress it.

Then the code would go something like this...

```
    // Obtain reference to file
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://blahblablah.com/file.txt");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    // Create the output ZIP file
    ZipArchiveOutputStream zip = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(zipFile);

    try {
        // Write a file header in the .zip file
        ArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry("file.txt");
        zip.putArchiveEntry(entry);

        // Download the file and write it to a compressed file
        IOUtils.copy(httpEntity.getContent(), zip);

        // The file is now written
        zip.closeArchiveEntry();
    } finally {
        // Ensure output file is closed
        zip.close();
    }
```

How does it work? HttpComponents is obtaining an `InputStream` of the file, and Compress is providing an `OutputStream`. Then you're just copying from one stream into the other. It's like magic!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same but you have to use a couple of methods:

```
String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/your_folder/your_file");
```

filepath is the absolute filesystem path (C:/.../WEB-INF/your_folder/your_file)

Comment: Uhm, that isn't want I want to do. Apparently the file needs to be a JAR file? Nevertheless, isn't there any simpler methods to ZIP a file from a webserver? and not from your drive.

Answer (score 0):

By 'zip a file on the web' it sounds like you mean doing so programatically within code in a web or application server.

This page may help. It discusses how to use the java.util.zip package: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/